# Can't run EntityGraphQL endpoint from virtual directory in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, entitygraph, entitygraphql

I'm using EntityGraphql https://entitygraphql.github.io/ But I can't get it to work if my app is deployed in a virtual folder in IIS

<del>This Works:</del>  (doesn't work either)

http://server/service

This does not work:

http://server/services/service

Altair UI and app client fails with a 400 bad request, but no specific error

program.cs:

```cs
...
builder.Services.AddGraphQLSchema<Db>(MyNamespace.Web.Schema.AddGraphQlOptions);
...
app.UseEndpoints(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.MapControllers();

    routeBuilder.MapGraphQL<Db>();//fails
    routeBuilder.MapGraphQL<Db>(path:"services/service/graphql");//fails
    routeBuilder.MapGraphQL<Db>(path: "/services/service/graphql");//fails

    routeBuilder.MapGraphQLAltair(new AltairOptions
    {
        GraphQLEndPoint = PathString.FromUriComponent("/services/service/graphql")
    });
});
...
```

Using ASP.NET 6 in IIS 10
EntityGraphQL 5.1.1
[image]

##### EDIT

The question is wrong, it doesn't work with any path, virtual folder or not, it fails with a 400, tried to use a direct path and got:

[image]

It's trying to reach a CDN library, my server does not have access to internet, how does this affect?

Comment: You cannot find the reason for the error from the client, only the server.  Since the code works with the route "http://server/service" and doesn't work with the route "http://server/services/service" the server doesn't like the bad route and is returning an error.  Does code work when you are not using a virtual server?  The files should be the same in both a regular server and a virtual server.  Maybe a file is missing when you deployed on the virtual server or the permission are different in the virtual server.

Comment: "Does code work when you are not using a virtual server?" let me try

Comment: @jdweng tried a direct path, failed, it's trying to reach a cdn library, but I think this should only affect altair/ui and not the graphql endpoint, right?

Answer (score 0):

It was the connection string

I forgot that EntityGraphQL grabs the conn string directly from the dbcontext configuration

```
routeBuilder.MapGraphQL<Db>();
```

In my Db I had a conn string for development
dbContext:

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=... bla bla
```

Make sure you're using the right conn string...